# jquery date picker

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui, datepicker

I am using **jquery date picker** in rails project, I want to **disable** the `previous/ past` dates.

Is there any way to achieve this. as well as the time if less that current

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Disable all dates till today :

```
// get the current date
var date = new Date();
var m = date.getMonth(), d = date.getDate(), y = date.getFullYear();

// Disable all dates till today
$('#datepicker2').datepicker({
        minDate: new Date(y, m, d),
        dateFormat: 'mm-dd-yy',
});
```

see more good option in this [post](http://articles.tutorboy.com/jquery/jquery-ui-datepicker-disable-specified-dates.html)

Comment: the link is very useful for me, i will definitely use that, but i also need to disable the past time for current date. Now i m using datetimepicker for other functionality, where i need time..

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the minDate option to the current date?

http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#option-minDate